# Command Handler/Parser for a railway simulation

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line, command-line-arguments

> I am trying to find a good way to create a user interface for my railway simulation.
>
> For now, I have created a "Command" interface with the methods *execute*, *getName*, *getArguments* and then I created a class for each command (AddTrack, DeleteTrack, ..., Exit). 
>   However, I am still struggling with a good way to get all arguments, handling wrong inputs etc. Does someone have a better idea for my UI or can give me some basic structure for it?
>
> Here is the list of all commands that I want to implement:

```
 - add track <startpoint> -> <endpoint>
 - delete track <trackID>
 - list tracks
 - set switch <trackID> position <point>
 - create engine <engineType> <class> <name> <length> <couplingFront> <couplingBack>
 - list engines
 - create coach <coachType> <length> <couplingFront> <couplingBack>
 - list coaches
 - create train-set <class> <name> <length> <couplingFront> <couplingBack>
 - list train-sets
 - delete rolling stock <id>
 - add train <trainID> <rollingStockID>
 - list trains
 - show train <trainID>
 - put train <trainID> at <point> in direction <x>,<y>
 - step <speed>
 - exit
```

To put them all in the same method is probably a bad practice. That's why my plan is to create a new class for each command.

My problem is that I am not sure how identify the commands since some consist of one word (like exit, step) and some consist of two words (add track, delete track, set switch). Would you recommend to create one class for all Add commands (add track, add train, ...), List commands (list tracks, list engines, ...) and so on?

Comment: Could someone please give me a concrete implementation structure?  I've been trying to work this out all day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to create a command-line tool, I would create some specific class related to the 'menu' (command handling) and then have specific classes for the specific domains (things related to trains, tracks, engines and so on).

So you might end up having a bit bloated command handling which holds some state (like where in the cli-app are we), let the user select some sort of state (if he wants to manipulate tracks, trains or see information about the engines). All that stuff is handled within a (or a few) menu classes. This class is responsible for holding state and 'navigate' the user (which means calling other classes and methods).